# Parameterizing same curve in different directions

Tags: parametrization

$$\textbf{r}_1(t)= \sin t \textbf{i}+ \cos t \textbf{j}$$ 
and
$$\textbf{r}_2(t)= \cos t \textbf{i}+ \sin t \textbf{j}$$
represent the same curve but traversed in different directions. $\textbf{r}_1$ clockwise and $\textbf{r}_2$ anticlockwise. It is not obvious to me just why this is case? Is there a way to determine  direction other than trial and error?

Comment: Not obvious to you why it's the same curve, or not obvious that the orientation is changed?

Comment: Why the orientation is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe representing the two curves slightly differently will help.
\begin{eqnarray}
r_1(t)=\begin{pmatrix}\sin(t)\\\cos (t)\end{pmatrix} \quad r_2(t)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos (t)\\\sin(t)\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}
in your $\textbf{i},\textbf{j}$ basis. Also the derivatives are
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{r}_1(t)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t)\\-\sin (t)\end{pmatrix} \quad \dot{r}_2(t)=\begin{pmatrix}-\sin(t)\\\cos(t)\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}
Let's also find a common point for which the curves are the same,for example $r_1(\pi/2)=r_2(0)$. Now the direction of the derivatives at this point is opposite.
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{r}_1((\pi/2)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos((\pi/2)\\-\sin ((\pi/2)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\end{pmatrix} \quad \dot{r}_2(0)=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 7):

$\newcommand{\Vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$Two paths
$$
\Vec{r}_{1}(t) = f(t)\, \Vec{i} + g(t)\, \Vec{j},\quad
\Vec{r}_{2}(t) = g(t)\, \Vec{i} + f(t)\, \Vec{j}
$$
differ by reflection across the line $y = x$, which acts on Cartesian coordinates of points by $(x_{0}, y_{0}) \mapsto (y_{0}, x_{0})$.

Because your $\Vec{r}_{2}$ is the standard (counterclockwise, unit-speed) parametrization of unit circle in the plane, $\Vec{r}_{1}$ parametrizes the image of the unit circle after reflection across the diagonal, namely the unit circle itself. It's geometrically clear the direction of travel changes.

---

Incidentally, an arbitrary path can be reparametrized "in the opposite direction" by *making time run backward*. i.e., replacing $t$ by $-t$ (or more generally by $c - t$ for some constant $c$).

For example, the path
$$
\Vec{r}_{3}(t) = \Vec{r}_{2}(-t)
= \cos(-t)\, \Vec{i} + \sin(-t)\, \Vec{j}
= \cos t\, \Vec{i} - \sin t\, \Vec{j}
$$
is a clockwise, unit-speed parametrization of the unit circle.

The same is true of $\Vec{r}_{2}(\frac{\pi}{2} - t)$, which you can easily check is $\Vec{r}_{1}(t)$.

Generally, if you have a path $\Vec{r}$ with domain $[a, b]$, the customary idiom for reversing the direction is
$$
\Vec{r}^{-}(t) = \Vec{r}(a + b - t),\quad a \leq t \leq b.
$$
(Can you see why? :)

Answer (score 1):

To determine direction compute $r_i'(t)$. Recall that this is the displacement vector at $r_i(t)$ i.e it tells you the direction. For instance,

$$r_2'(0.01) \approx (-.01,1)$$

Hence at $r_2(0.01)$ we are moving in the direction of $(-.01,1)$ i.e if we are to stay on the circular path, we must be going in the counter-clockwise direction. I hope this makes sense. To detect the change in orientation, you can again look at the velocity vectors. Compare $r_1'(s_0)$ to $r_2'(t_0)$ where $r_1(s_0) = r_2(t_0)$.